# Refused to apply css styles in my Django App, because its MIME type its not supported

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a serious problem with my Django application and is that I do not load the styles in my app, the error I get in console is as follows:

```
"It has been rejected to apply the style of 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/static/css/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled".

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

**Settings.py:**

```
from email.mime import application
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

import os 

DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
MEDIA_URL = 'Imagenes/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Imagenes')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
    'clase',
    'index',
    'accounts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djanpro.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

...

this is **urls.py** file:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from djanpro.settings import MEDIA_ROOT

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include("index.urls")),
    path('clase/', include("clase.urls")),
    path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

for now I can only view the html of my platform, however the images that are saved in the posts seem to be working.

Comment: Please grab static file url from rendered page, open it in new tab and share what you get. Error message, some dialog or whatever.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the message I'm getting is "Directory indexes are not allowed here". You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django configuration file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: show your urls.py

Comment: already edited the post

Comment: MIME type error in django often means that some error page (html with error info) is displayed instead of whatever file. Please try opening static file url which gives the error manually and see what is returned (error message, http status). urls.py looks fine. Also please check what is the directory where static files are stored and verify that STATIC_ROOT points to that directory. Also shown static file URL contains double `static/static/` path which may be an error in a template where static url is build. Check that template or show this code. Try to run `collectstatic` to validate settings